# combine several lines in a CSV file into a single line based on a certain condition

Tags: linux, csv, awk

I am trying to read a CSV file in this format

```
COL1, COL2  
5, 25  
5, 67  
5, 89  
3, 55  
3, 8  
3, 109  
3, 12  
3, 45  
3, 663  
80, 34  
80, 5
```

and combine COL2 for all entries having the same COL1 in a single line such that the first column indicates the number of columns that follow. So for the sample given above, the output file should look like this:

```
3, 25, 67, 89  
6, 55, 8, 109, 12, 45, 663  
2, 34, 5
```

Comment: what programming language should be used, what have you tried already? why you haven't succeed. Basically, this is not site for creating code but for helping with code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{a[$1]=a[$1]", "$2;c[$1]++}END{for (k in a) print c[k] a[k]}'  file
3, 25, 67, 89
6, 55, 8, 109, 12, 45, 663
2, 34, 5
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, unfortunately it did not work. Nonetheless, thank you. I eventually wrote a Perl script. It took me the entire day and loads of googling since I haven't done any scripting in the past.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the script see it working here http://ideone.com/VTq0BI your input file must be different from the one posted in your question.